# CSS style button look difference in FF and Chromium

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is example:
http://jsbin.com/zirayuzose/2/

For some reason i need inputs with borders styled in wrapper elements, and it works fine andd looks fine in Chromium, but in Firefox "OK" button has different height here, which is should not happen according to CSS. Any idea how to struggle it.

HTML:

```
<div class="inpWrap" style="width:25%">
    <input class="inp" type="text">
</div>
<div class="inpWrap" style="width:110px">
    <button type="submit" class="inp1" style="margin: 0">OK</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inpWrap {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid orange;
}


.inp {
    width: 96%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    background: #fff;
}
.inp1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: try resetting your css. http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: Try giving `line-height` to the button

Answer (score 0):

With some minor adjustments it looks exactly as you want it
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="inpWrap" style="width:60%">
        <input class="inp" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="inpWrap" style="width:110px">
        <button type="submit" class="inp1">OK</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
 body {
      background: #fff;
    }  
    .inpWrap {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 2px solid orange;
        height:34px;
      vertical-align:middle;
    } 
    .inp {
        width: 96%;
        padding: 4px;
        font-size: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        background: transparent;
    }
    .inp1 {
        padding: 4px;
      height:34px;
        font-size: 20px;
         border: 1px solid #fff;
        background: transparent;
    }
```

try it: http://jsbin.com/hakajezuba/1/

Comment: Here you hardcode height, which is would be desirable to avoid, and in FF input field border looks corrupted

Comment: The above was tested on IE11, chrome,opera,and FF